# Exchange rule to avoid duplicate forwardings from user 1 to group A who is in group B

Tags: exchange, microsoft-office-365

I am trying to setup a set of rules, where a user 1 is inside of a group A, and also has a rule for outside of organization emails to forward as BCC to group B.

Also there are a user 2, 3 and 4, forwarding their outside organization emails to group A.

In practice, all mails from outside of this organization that went in group A, from group A, user 2, 3 and 4, goes for user 1, and the rule forwards all of those emails to group B.

I am still trying to setup a way to avoid it, but till now, didnt found it.

Any of you knows a way to avoid this?

Answer (score 1):

I have done a test in my exchange lab, i have created a transport rule look like this for your reference:
[image]